# Android Playstore speed problem on Stock Android phone

Tags: google-play-store, stock-android, internet, mi-a1, android-one

I am using Android One phone with Stock Android 8.0.0, I see some major speed problem in my playstore- while downloading from playstore I only get 250KBPS speed whereas my actual speed is 1.3MBPS -which I get in other apps..and even other phone's playstore while connected to the same network..
I don't know what is happening..
Any help and tips..?

Comment: With out more information it could be a bunch of different issues: Google could be throttling you download speed, your network router could be throttling it, or your internet provider could be throttling.  The play store is rather rudimentary IMO considering it historically doesn't allow the parallel downloading of applications

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is basically the problem of the software version  of the current update..There is no other way to wait for the next update.